# Switch statement syntax for same action through different cases

Tags: objective-c, c, switch-statement

Two constants (1+2) share the same case statement. I don´t want to double the code.

What is the right syntax to do this?

```
switch (expression) {
        case 0:
            [self taskA];
            break;
        case 1:
            [self taskB];
            break;
        case 2:
            [self taskB]
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use :

```
switch (expression) {
    case 0:
        [self taskA];
        break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
        [self taskB];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Edit 1:

In `switch` we say a term called **fall-through**. Whenever control reaches to a label say `case 0:` it falls till `break` is found. On `break` control is sent to the closing braces of `switch`.

If `break` is not encountered it goes to next `case` as in `case` then `case 2`. So above `case 1` and `case 2` shares one `break` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple case labels can refer to the same statement if break or return are not used at the end of the case. 
If you do not use a break statement in case 1, the execution flows into case 2.